# Object creation order with class having containment of other objects

Tags: c++

```
#include "iostream"
using namespace std;
class C
{
    public:
    C() { cout << "C's Constructor Called " << endl;  }
};

class A
{
    public:
    A() { cout << "A's Constructor Called " << endl;  }
    A(int) {  cout << "A's int Constructor Called " << endl;  }
};

class B
{ 
    public:
    A a;
    B() { cout << "B's Constructor Called " << endl; }
    B(int i) : a(i) { cout << "B's int Constructor Called " << endl; }
    C c;
};

int main()
{
    B b1(1);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:
    A's int Constructor Called
    C's Constructor Called
    B's int Constructor Called

Question :
Why output does not contain "A's Constructor Called"
According to me i thought Output would be like below :
    A's Constructor Called
    C's Constructor Called
    B's int Constructor Called

Wondering why A a does not lead to constructor A() being called but only A(int) because of a(i)

Comment: I don't get your question.  `A's int Constructor Called` is the first line in your output.

Comment: Because it's being initialized with the `A(int)` constructor.

Comment: @NathanOliver I guess he is wondering why `A a` does not lead to constructor `A()` being called but only `A(int)` because of `a(i)`
Maybe not clearly asked but a good question

Comment: Odysseus : You are correct. I have updated my question. Thanks for clarifying it.

Comment: As an exercise, change your definition of `B(int i)...` to `B(int i) { cout << "B's int Constructor Called " << endl; a = A(i); }` (move `a(i)` from the initialization list to `a = A(i);` in the function body) to see why initialization lists are preferred for member construction.

Comment: @NathanOliver : I have edited the question to put more clarity. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

C++ always calls only exactly one constructor of a class.

In your case, the compiler chooses the `A(int)` constructor (since that's what you're using in `B`) and therefore never calls any other constructor.

Comment: only calls exactly **one** ?

Comment: and then "never calls any one constructor" -> "never calls any other constructor" ?

Comment: Exactly. Thanks.

Comment: Sometimes no constructors are called (e.g. aggregate initialization)

Answer (score 1):

> Wondering why A a does not lead to constructor A() being called but only A(int) because of a(i)

`A a;` is only a declaration of a field member of `class B`. This does **not** initialize the variable in the same way a local declaration would. Instead, the initialization occurs in the `B()` constructor when you do `a(i)`. This calls the `A(int)` constructor. The no-argument constructor will never be called here.

Answer (score 0):

A's constructor is not called because it is overridden by the parameterised constructor in the initialisation list here - B(int i) : a(i).

If you observe carefully "B's Constructor Called" is also not printed because of the same reason.

Answer (score 0):

Simply because you have initialized it in B's constructor-initializer-list via A's constructor that takes an integer.

```
B(int i) : a(i) { cout << "B's int Constructor Called " << endl; }
```

You can get "A's constructor called" if you called it or didn't initialize it then it is default-intialized:

```
B(int i) : a() { cout << "B's int Constructor Called " << endl; } // a is value-initialized which is here the same as default-initialized.
```